# Why does SQL-Server sort clustered index column of merge joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, join, clustered-index

lets assume I have the following tables, filled with millions of records:

```
create table table1 (
    id int not null
);
alter table table1 add constraint pk_table1_id primary key (
    id asc
);

create table table2 (
    t1_id int not null,
    id int not null
);
alter table table2 add constraint pk_table2_t1_id_id primary key (
    t1_id asc,
    id asc
);
```

I want to join those tables like this:

```
select
*
from
table1 t1
left join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.t1_id
order by t1.id--, t2.id
```

SQL-Server (2005) produces the the following execution plan:

[image]

SQL-Server correctly chooses the merge-join-operation and eliminates the sort-operation, because both tables are already sorted using the id column of table1.

Now if I uncomment the second part of the order-by-clause, which uses the second key of the primary key of table2, SQL-Server uses the following plan:

[image]
Even if I use the merge-join-hint, SQL-Server sorts the data after joining the two tables.

### My questions:

- Why does SQL-Server have to sort the data of the indexed column?
- Is there a way to change the query, table columns or indexes, which lets SQL-Server eliminate this specific sort-operation?

Comment: The second plan is parallel, and the final outcome requires another sorting step to integrate the parallel streams. `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` tells SQL Server to not consider parallelism and should yield the first plan again, at the cost of potentially making the query as a whole slower.

Comment: I already tried this option. SQL-Server chooses the loop-join now, but if I use the merge-join-hint, SQL-Server still has to sort the data. I thought that the merge-join is faster and more efficent for this kind of problem, but obviously not, if the data has to be sorted for whatever reason.

Comment: Assuming a sufficient number of rows, yes, a merge join is typically more efficient on data that's already sorted. This may be a shortcoming in the optimizer, where it fails to match the partial sort order of the index with the `ORDER BY` ordering. If this is the case, then adding the "redundant" sort yourself would be superior. Measure to see what's what. (`SET STATISTICS IO ON`, `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`.)

Comment: The problem is even more interesting. It is using the `SORT` even when you use `ORDER BY t2.t1_id, t2.id`, which is strange.